# PHP Extend object

Tags: php, laravel, object

I've just a question about extending objects.
I'm using laravel_imap package in my project to create a custom made email client. Whenever you fetch data like folders for example, you'll get a collection of `Webklex\PHPIMAP\Folder` objects.
But how do I exactly extend their functionality by adding additional variables to it?

By passing Folder object to constructor? If so, I whenever I need to access data from the original folder object, I need to call a function like `getImapFolder(): Webklex\PHPIMAPFolder`. Right?

By using keyword extend? If so, I cannot control whether to get CustomFolder from imap server, it's always `Webklex\PHPIMAP\Folder`.

By storing in array? Weird way I think.

Any ideas of how to "extend" these objects correctly?

Thank you.

Comment: Share the github link to the package please

Comment: https://github.com/Webklex/laravel-imap

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to fetch the folders and what you want to extend/add concretely? `webklex/laravel-imap` uses `webklex/php-imap` in the background, so most of the stuff is in that other package.

Comment: Since you are working with a 3rd party library, questions about extensibility should probably be directed towards the library authors. It may not be possible as well depending on how they build the library. What you can do if you want to provide funcitonality to `Folder` is to create a utility class e.g. one with static methods that accept a `Folder` argument and provide the extra functionality you need